# Trying to create database in mezzanine django, and getting strange error

Tags: django, mezzanine

I've created a virtual environment for a mezzanine project containing the following dependencie

```html
Django==1.7.1
Fabric==1.10.1
Mezzanine==3.1.10
argparse==1.2.1
bleach==1.4.1
django-filebrowser==3.5.7
django-grappelli==2.6.3
future==0.14.3
grappelli-safe==0.3.13
html5lib==0.999
importlib==1.0.3
mezzanine-grappelli==0.1.0
pytz==2014.10
six==1.8.0
unittest2==0.8.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

When I try to run the 'python manage.py createdb' command I get the following error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/JoeDevelopsSite/manage.py", line 28, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/forms/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mezzanine.forms import fields
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/forms/fields.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mezzanine.core.forms import SplitSelectDateTimeWidget
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/forms.py", line 40, in <module>
    if settings.GRAPPELLI_INSTALLED:
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/conf/__init__.py", line 184, in __getattr__
    return getattr(django_settings, name)
  File "/home/joe/JoeDevelopsSite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'GRAPPELLI_INSTALLED'
```

Here's the full settings.py file:

```html
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

######################
# MEZZANINE SETTINGS #
######################

# The following settings are already defined with default values in
# the ``defaults.py`` module within each of Mezzanine's apps, but are
# common enough to be put here, commented out, for convenient
# overriding. Please consult the settings documentation for a full list
# of settings Mezzanine implements:
# http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html#default-settings

# Controls the ordering and grouping of the admin menu.
#
# ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
#     ("Content", ("pages.Page", "blog.BlogPost",
#        "generic.ThreadedComment", ("Media Library", "fb_browse"),)),
#     ("Site", ("sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect", "conf.Setting")),
#     ("Users", ("auth.User", "auth.Group",)),
# )

# A three item sequence, each containing a sequence of template tags
# used to render the admin dashboard.
#
# DASHBOARD_TAGS = (
#     ("blog_tags.quick_blog", "mezzanine_tags.app_list"),
#     ("comment_tags.recent_comments",),
#     ("mezzanine_tags.recent_actions",),
# )
#
# A sequence of templates used by the ``page_menu`` template tag. Each
# item in the sequence is a three item sequence, containing a unique ID
# for the template, a label for the template, and the template path.
# These templates are then available for selection when editing which
# menus a page should appear in. Note that if a menu template is used
# that doesn't appear in this setting, all pages will appear in it.

# PAGE_MENU_TEMPLATES = (
#     (1, "Top navigation bar", "pages/menus/dropdown.html"),
#     (2, "Left-hand tree", "pages/menus/tree.html"),
#     (3, "Footer", "pages/menus/footer.html"),
# )

# A sequence of fields that will be injected into Mezzanine's (or any
# library's) models. Each item in the sequence is a four item sequence.
# The first two items are the dotted path to the model and its field
# name to be added, and the dotted path to the field class to use for
# the field. The third and fourth items are a sequence of positional
# args and a dictionary of keyword args, to use when creating the
# field instance. When specifying the field class, the path
# ``django.models.db.`` can be omitted for regular Django model fields.
# 
# EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
#     (
#         # Dotted path to field.
#         "mezzanine.blog.models.BlogPost.image",
#         # Dotted path to field class.
#         "somelib.fields.ImageField",
#         # Positional args for field class.
#         ("Image",),
#         # Keyword args for field class.
#         {"blank": True, "upload_to": "blog"},
#     ),
#     # Example of adding a field to *all* of Mezzanine's content types:
#     (
#         "mezzanine.pages.models.Page.another_field",
#         "IntegerField", # 'django.db.models.' is implied if path is omitted.
#         ("Another name",),
#         {"blank": True, "default": 1},
#     ),
# )

# Setting to turn on featured images for blog posts. Defaults to False.
#         
# BLOG_USE_FEATURED_IMAGE = True

# If True, the south application will be automatically added to the
# INSTALLED_APPS setting.
USE_SOUTH = True


######################### MAIN DJANGO SETTINGS #
########################

# People who get code error notifications.
# In the format (('Full Name', 'email@example.com'),
#                ('Full Name', 'anotheremail@example.com'))
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = None

# If you set this to True, Django will use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

# Supported languages
_ = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
)

# A boolean that turns on/off debug mode. When set to ``True``, stack traces
# are displayed for error pages. Should always be set to ``False`` in
# production. Best set to ``True`` in local_settings.py
DEBUG = False

# Whether a user's session cookie expires when the Web browser is closed.
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

SITE_ID = 1
# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = False

# Tuple of IP addresses, as strings, that:
#   * See debug comments, when DEBUG is true
#   * Receive x-headers
INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1",)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("mezzanine.core.auth_backends.MezzanineBackend",)
# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# The numeric mode to set newly-uploaded files to. The value should be
# a mode you'd pass directly to os.chmod.
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644


#############
# DATABASES#############

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        # Add "postgresql_psycopg2", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.",
        # DB name or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "NAME": "",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "USER": "",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "",
        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "",
        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "",
    }
}


#########
# PATHS #
#########
#import os

# Full filesystem path to the project.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Name of the directory for the project.
PROJECT_DIRNAME = PROJECT_ROOT.split(os.sep)[-1]

# Every cache key will get prefixed with this value - here we set it to
# the name of the directory the project is in to try and use something
# project specific.
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = PROJECT_DIRNAME

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))
# Package/module name to import the root urlpatterns from for the project.
ROOT_URLCONF = "%s.urls" % PROJECT_DIRNAME

# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates"
# or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)


################
# APPLICATIONS #
################

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    #"mezzanine.accounts",
    #"mezzanine.mobile",
)
# List of processors used by RequestContext to populate the context.
# Each one should be a callable that takes the request object as its
# only parameter and returns a dictionary to add to the context.
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "mezzanine.conf.context_processors.settings",
    "mezzanine.pages.context_processors.page",
)
# List of middleware classes to use. Order is important; in the request phase,
# these middleware classes will be applied in the order given, and in the
# response phase the middleware will be applied in reverse order.
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
    # Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:
    # "mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
)

# Store these package names here as they may change in the future since
# at the moment we are using custom forks of them.
PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER = "filebrowser_safe"
PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI = "grappelli_safe"

#########################
# OPTIONAL APPLICATIONS #
#########################

# These will be added to ``INSTALLED_APPS``, only if available.
OPTIONAL_APPS = (
    "debug_toolbar",
    "django_extensions",
    "compressor",
    PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER,
    PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI,
)

###################
# DEPLOY SETTINGS #
###################

# These settings are used by the default fabfile.py provided.
# Check fabfile.py for defaults.

#FABRIC = {
#     "SSH_USER": "", # SSH username for host deploying to
#     "HOSTS": ALLOWED_HOSTS[:1], # List of hosts to deploy to (eg, first host)
#     "DOMAINS": ALLOWED_HOSTS, # Domains for public site
#     "REPO_URL": "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/project", # Project's repo URL
#     "VIRTUALENV_HOME":  "", # Absolute remote path for virtualenvs
#     "PROJECT_NAME": "", # Unique identifier for project
#     "REQUIREMENTS_PATH": "requirements.txt", # Project's pip requirements
#     "GUNICORN_PORT": 8000, # Port gunicorn will listen on
#     "LOCALE": "en_US.UTF-8", # Should end with ".UTF-8"
#     "DB_PASS": "", # Live database password
#     "ADMIN_PASS": "", # Live admin user password
#     "SECRET_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
#     "NEVERCACHE_KEY": NEVERCACHE_KEY,
# }


##################
# LOCAL SETTINGS #
##################

# Allow any settings to be defined in local_settings.py which should be
# ignored in your version control system allowing for settings to be
# defined per machine.
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError as e:
    if "local_settings" not in str(e):
        raise e


####################
# DYNAMIC SETTINGS #
####################

# set_dynamic_settings() will rewrite globals based on what has been
# defined so far, in order to provide some better defaults where
# applicable. We also allow this settings module to be imported
# without Mezzanine installed, as the case may be when using the
# fabfile, where setting the dynamic settings below isn't strictly
# required.
try:
    from mezzanine.utils.conf import set_dynamic_settings
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    set_dynamic_settings(globals())
```

I've been unable to find a solution to this error.  Would love guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: @halfnibble After installing other dependencies as well as Pillow, the same error is still present.

Comment: Please post your setting content. Do you have PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI = "grappelli_safe" in your settings?

Comment: @Aldarund:
# Store these package names here as they may change in the future since
# at the moment we are using custom forks of them.
PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER = "filebrowser_safe"
PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI = "grappelli_safe"

Comment: Could it possibly have anything to do with configuring Fabric in settings.py?

Comment: please provide your full settings.py file.

Comment: @Aldarund Updated question to include settings.py

Comment: It looks like some error happens on this stage: from mezzanine.utils.conf import set_dynamic_settings
Can you replace pass statement with some error printing, so maybe we will see what is wrong

Comment: @Aldarund What kind of error printing are you referring to?  Sorry if this seems like a novice question.

Comment: You can just print E. Anyway i guess your problem is that you are using dajngo 1.7 and mezzanine release which is compatible with 1.6. So you can either downgrade django or use trunk version of mezzanine

Comment: @Aldarund This was exactly the problem, thank you.  Now I've begun the process of banging my head against the wall figuring out how my project is supposed to be  served through my nginx server.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mezzanine works with Django 1.6.  An incorrect version of Django was being used.